# Android: Background Thread set to sleep, but still blocks UITread

Tags: android, multithreading, background, sleep, ui-thread

I created simple example in Android: on a button click, a new Thread is created run in backgroud.
However when I put it to sleep (`Thread.sleeps(10000)`) it blocks also the UIThread.

Why it blocks also the UIThread? My thread is supposed to run in background in asynchronous way. Is there any way to run a Thread in background without using `AsyncTask` and `doInBackground` method? Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Here the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) { return true;  }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void dothings(View view){
        new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                try{Thread.sleep(10000);}
                catch(Exception e){}
            }
        }.run();

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"CIao",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to call `Start()` function and not `run()` function

Answer (score 0):

To provide more details on Itzik's answer which is correct, by calling `run()` on the thread instance you are actually executing the `run` method in which you defined the sleep to happen. You're seeing the UI freeze up for those 10 seconds since this is being called from the main thread.

`start()` will actually begin the execution of the thread, with the VM executing the run() method of the thread.